# Bottstrap functionality not working inside leaflet's L.DomUtil element

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, leaflet, bootstrap-modal

I have an html code (string) received in AJAX call. It has dropdowns and other bootstrap related stuff which is working fine if i put it in modal content like this:

```
$("#modal-form .modal-content").html(html_string);
```

but if i put it as a content to dynamically created window (`L.DomUtil.create('div',..)`) it's not working, in case of dropdown it's not toggling. Seems like this html not evaluated by bootstrap.

HTML:

```
  <div class="modal fade autoclean" id="modal-form">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This works fine:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://.....,
  success: function (html_str) {
    $("#modal-form .modal-content").html(html_str);
    $("#modal-form").modal("show");
  }
});
```

This is not:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://.....,
  success: function (html_str) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'my-div', container);
    div.innerHTML(html_str);
  }
});
```

L.DomUtil is utility method for creating DOM structures.
(https://docs.eegeo.com/eegeo.js/v0.1.780/docs/leaflet/L.DomUtil)

Comment: Could you add a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

After creating the new div try adding a class to it with something like this:

`document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add(".modal-content")`

Or...

`document.getElementById("myDIV").setAttribute("id", "#modal-form");`

So if you create a div element and save it to a myDiv variable you can

`myDiv.setAttribute("id", "#modal-form");`

or

`myDiv.classList.add(".modal-content")`

Answer (score 0):

It's disabled in the sources L.DomEvent.on(this._wrapper, 'click', stop), and clicks are not firing making a confidence bootstrap's are not applying.